# c++ confusing state variable behaviour

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, c++11

I have a class "CardT" the contains a suit and number stored by an enum value. For the use of solitaire i create a deck of 52 of these cards with each value. I also have a "tableau" class that stores a set of these cards for the solitaire tableau, my board class contains an array of 8 of these. After placing the values in the array and printing to check for correctness, it gives a correct output. But if i then call another function right after that prints the exact same thing, i get very different values.

```
int main(){
    Board b;
    b.setUp();  //setUp deck and add to tableau arrays
    b.printTab(4); //print the fourth one again
}
```

Where deck gets setup

```
void Board::setUp(){
//here i setup all 52
CardT deck[52];
int c = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <=13;j++){
        deck[c] = CardT(static_cast<CardSuit>(i),static_cast<CardNum>(j));
        c++;
    }
//shuffle
std::random_shuffle(&deck[0],&deck[52]);

CardT tabls[8][13]; 
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        tabls[i][j] = deck[j + i*8];  //the first 4 piles that contain 8 cards

for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 7;j++)
        tabls[i][j] = deck[j + i*8]; //last four with seven

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    this->tableauPiles[i] = TableauPileT(tabls[i],8); //place first four, (second param is size)

for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++)
    this->tableauPiles[i] = TableauPileT(tabls[i],7); //place second four

for (int i = 0; i < 4;i++)
    this->foundationPiles[i] = FoundationPileT(); //just intialize


//FOR testing
for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++){
    if (this->tableauPiles[4].cardAtIndex(j)){
        std::cout << this->tableauPiles[4].getCardByIndex(j).getNum() << ",,,," << this->tableauPiles[4].getCardByIndex(j).getSuit() << std::endl;

    }
}
//printed twice for assurance, both print as expected
for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++){
    if (this->tableauPiles[4].cardAtIndex(j)){
        std::cout << this->tableauPiles[4].getCardByIndex(j).getNum() << ",,-,," << this->tableauPiles[4].getCardByIndex(j).getSuit() << std::endl;

    }
}


}
```

Heres where i then print the exact same thing again:

```
void Board::printTab(int i){
    for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++){
        if (this->tableauPiles[4].cardAtIndex(j)){
            std::cout << this->tableauPiles[4].getCardByIndex(j).getNum() << ",,Third,," << this->tableauPiles[4].getCardByIndex(j).getSuit() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

}

The header for the board

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H

class Board{
private:

CardT freeCells[4];
bool freeCellsOpen[4] = {false,false,false,false};
FoundationPileT foundationPiles[4];
TableauPileT tableauPiles[8];

int cardPosition(CardNum n, CardSuit s);
int emptyFreeCell();

public:

Board();
void setUp();
void moveToFreeCell(CardNum n, CardSuit s);
void moveToTableau(CardNum n, CardSuit s, int tableau);
void moveToFoundation(CardNum n, CardSuit s);
void printBoard();
void printTab(int i);
};


#endif
```

And finally this is then the output im given

```
1,,,,1
12,,,,2
4,,,,0
4,,,,1
4,,,,2
5,,,,3
10,,,,0
1,,-,,1
12,,-,,2
4,,-,,0
4,,-,,1
4,,-,,2
5,,-,,3
10,,-,,0
1,,Third,,1
0,,Third,,1
0,,Third,,0
32545,,Third,,1284192187
0,,Third,,10
32767,,Third,,1922833024
0,,Third,,0
```

The printed values are stored as enum.

Clearly changed between print statements, very new to c++ but have c experience among others. Any help is greatly appreciated as im going out of my mind.

Also im printing the 4th pile, i believe the 0-3 pile all print correctly, just 4+ are getting messed.

Also of note, the large unexpected values are changing between executions, rest stay constant.

Comment: Why are you casting this line   `std::cout << (int) this->tableauPiles[4].getCardByIndex(j).getNum() << ",,Third,," << (int) this->tableauPiles[4].getCardByIndex(j).getSuit() << std::endl;` as ints, but none of your other printouts?

Comment: @ChrisHandy mb, i meant to remove that before posting, was just for interest, is edited. thanks!

Comment: When you doing assignments to the cards, for example, like `this->tableauPiles[i] = TableauPileT(tabls[i],8);` are you doing a deep copy? If not these things are dropping out of scope and you are seeing random memory

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code you posted. Could you try to prepare a [mcve]? Put everything in one file, delete the stuff that is not needed. http://codepad.org/IoqQvO1c

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg You can just put `[mcve]` in your comment and it'll produce a link like this: [mcve]

Comment: @melpomene Cool, thanks. :)

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg i added the link to the end of my post. Weirdly their compiler makes it work much better. Although last values arnt working for them (producing 0), while producing something for me in original print. But on the third print theirs works to post the same (mind you incorrect) values, but mine as posted gives weird behaviour... Im using g++ with std11 tag

Comment: @ChrisHandy From my understanding it would be a shallow copy? how could I force it to be a deep one to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your card tables (`CardT tabls[8][13];`) are declared on the stack on your `Board::setUp()` method.

You then store pointers to these in your TableauPileT objects.
This works fine for your debug code because they are still on the stack,
but at the time you call the `printTab` function they have been deallocated.

So you're just reading whatever is left over in memory at that point, meaning you're getting undefined behaviour.

Comment: Okay makes sense, my gap of time since c is showing clearly. How would i do a deep copy for this? or does it require being done explicitly

Comment: I would recommend ideally using a std::vector inside the TableauPile. If not that, then declare tabls as a member of your Board object instead of on the stack.

Comment: Not just tabls, but you would also want `CardT deck[52];` to be part of your board object. Your issue is that `TableauPileT` has a **pointer** to a list of cards, those cards are on the stack. When returning from the method this is now random memory.

Answer (score 1):

2nd loop after shuffle: why do you multiply i by 8 while the pile is just 6 cards? Obviously going out of array bounds. Should be `[j+4+i*6]`. By the way, the first 4 piles are only 7 cards long and multiplication of i by 8 is wrong. In those table initiating loops, j should be less than 7 and 6 respectively instead of 8 and 7.

Comment: yea i changed all the ranges and such once the printing got working and i could see. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. But most probably, I wouldn't write code like that. A lot can be done to increase the quality of this code, but I am too old.